# Let $f\colon\Bbb Z\to R$ be a surjective homomorphism. Show that $R$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f\colon\mathbb Z\to R$ be a surjective homomorphism. Show that $R$ is isomorphic either to $\mathbb Z$ or to the ring $\mathbb{Z/nZ}$ for suitable $n \geq 1$

I have no clue on this question, please help me, thanks

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 2):

The first isomorphism theorem for rings says, among other things, that if $R,S$ are rings and $f: R \rightarrow S$ is a surjective homomorphism then $S \cong R / \ker f$. In the context of your question then it remains to determine what the possibilities are for $\ker f$. In particular $\ker f$ is an ideal of $\mathbb Z$. So you need to show that the ideals of $\mathbb Z$ are $n\mathbb Z$ and $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\mathbb Z$ is generated additively by $1$, $R$ is generated additively by $f(1)$.  If $f(1)$ has infinite additive order, then you can show that $R\cong \mathbb Z$.  If $f(1)$ has additive order $n$, then you can show that $R\cong \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
The only subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\{0\}$ and $n\mathbb{Z}, \ n \in \mathbb{N}$. 
Thus the only possibilities of $\mathbb{Z}/\text{Ker} f$ are $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n , \ n \in \mathbb{N}\ldots$